# Angularjs filtering input

Tags: html, angularjs, filter

I need to create input for numbers so if user entering 10000, in input will be displayed 10 000 or 10.000, but in model in will be 10000. Tried to make something like

```
<input type="text" ng-model="value" ng-pattern="/(\d+)(\d{3})/">
```

But it doesn't works(

Comment: Take a look here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency

Comment: @DragoşPaulMarinescu yep, but I need to use this filter in input, and as I know it is impossible to use filter in input in angularjs

Comment: True, my bad. Look into using a custom directive, e.g : https://github.com/assisrafael/angular-input-masks

Comment: @mir Thank you!!! Thats what I need!)

Comment: @RoGGeR can you flag the comment like usefel thnx :)

Comment: @mir of course! How to do that? If I click flag there is a list of three reasons to report comment, but not to flag it as usefel or smth like this.

Comment: @RoGGeR ther is an icon that  says ''this comment adds somthings usefel...

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need some trick here. You need to show it in a label but edit in a textbox. Some thing like this

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="InputCtrl">
<input id="id" type="number" ng-model="mynum1"><label for="id">{{mynum1 | number}}</label><br>
```

I've create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LCZfd/968/) may be this is help full to you.